# Why doesn't my vector's elementCount increase when I create this Swing JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've inherited a Java application utilizing Swing, which I have precisely zero experience in, so bear with me.

I'm receiving this error when I attempt to open a feature of the application:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >= 0
  at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
  at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
  at AssetTable$ComponentTable.<init>(AssetTable.java:69)
```

The table model's class looks like this:

```
   static class ComponentTable extends JTable
   {
     JComboBox ocTypesCBox;
     AssetTable.ComponentTable.ComponentTableModel ctmodel;

     public ComponentTable(AssetTable.ComponentTable.ComponentTableModel ctm)
     {
       super();
       this.ocTypesCBox = new JComboBox();
       this.ocTypesCBox.addItem("1");
       this.ocTypesCBox.addItem("2");
       this.ocTypesCBox.addItem("3");
       this.ocTypesCBox.addItem("4");
       getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(this.ocTypesCBox));
       this.ctmodel = ctm;
     }

     public void setData(OnlineComponent oc) {
       Object[][] ocData = { { oc.getCode(), oc.getIntegratorId(), oc.getPP(), oc.getType() } };
       setData(ocData);
     }

     public void setData(Object[][] data)
     {
       this.ctmodel.setData(data);
     }

     public Object[][] getData() {
       return this.ctmodel.getData();
     }

     static class ComponentTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
       String[] ocColumns = { "Component_Code", "Integrator_ID", "Popup_Properties", "Type" };
       Object[][] ocData = { { "", "", "", "" } };

       public void setData(Object[][] ocData) {
         this.ocData = ocData;
         fireTableDataChanged();
       }
       public Object[][] getData() {
         return this.ocData;
       }
       public int getColumnCount() { return this.ocColumns.length; }


       public int getRowCount()
       {
         return this.ocData.length;
       }

       public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
       {
         if (AssetTable.AssetTableModel.course) return true;
         return false;
       }

       public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
       {
         return this.ocData[row][col];
       }

       public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)
       {
         this.ocData[row][col] = (value == null ? "" : (String)value);
         fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
       }

       public String getColumnName(int col) {
         return this.ocColumns[col];
       }
     }
   }
```

The error is occuring on that `getColumn(3)` call.  It seems to me those `addItem` methods aren't actually increasing the expected size of the `elementCount` for this table.  Why would that be the case?

I suspect this is nowhere near enough code to go on but I'm not sure what would be relevant and what would be TMI.  If you  can think of something additional that would help, I'll try to track it down and post it as an edit.

Comment: The addItem() is an method of the JComboBox. addItem() increasing the elementcount/itemcount of the JComboBox. getColumnModel() gets a tablemodel and not the combobox. Thats two different Components

Comment: So the problem is my tablemodel is empty?

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: yes, your tablemodel must have 4 columns (column 0, column 1, column 2, column 3) and then getColumn(3) gets an result.

Comment: updated to include the whole table's class.  when I debug the elementCount never seems to get set at all by the time I invoke the error.  You can see the static class `ComponentTableModel` does seem to lay out four columns when it's created.

Comment: you never use setModel(); to set yout tablemodel to your JTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use:

```
super(ctm);
```

this sets the tablemodel to the JTable by the constructor